# retaining time stamp hour value while conversion from String to Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, db2, timestamp

I have timestamp read from database into a string as below:

Source database table timestamp field value is as below:

```
8/21/2012 2:09 AM
```

I am reading above timestamp into a String field in a java program.

However, while writing it into destination database table, I am reconverting the String back into time stamp using below code:

```
java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date newDate = format.parse(item.getMyTimeStamp());
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(newDate.getTime()));
```

However, the timestamp field value in the destination table is coming as below:

```
8/21/2012 12:00 AM
```

As clear the hour field is getting reset to 12 AM.

How can I retain the original timestamp value?

Comment: Why are you involving a `string` here? Why don't you insert source database value as it is to the destination table?

Comment: @bonCodigo: This is part of a Spring batch program. And I can not do what you are suggesting. I must convert the String back to correct timestamp.

Comment: What is the correct time stamp? Source is returning the correct time stamp according to your question. Then only during the conversion things go nuts. Have you thought of using a `prepared statment`.

Comment: @bonCodigo: ps is prepared statement. Update the question with format I am using. I think the issue is there. But I dont know the correct format value to put.

Comment: You are aware that a timestamp has both date and time components?  Using SimpleDateFormat with only the date ("yyyy-MM-dd") is truncating  your timestamp.  @bonCodigo is correct.  It's like storing Pi in an Integer and then wondering where your precision went.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde: Thanks for the comment, however, I have clearly admitted in my other comments that I know that that's where the problem is and I am unable to find the correct format string. So if possible could you please answer the precise format which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nikunj this `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` is literally losing your `timestamp`...so it sets the time into `12AM`.... you need to get the **precise format.**

Can you please try this, Assuming your string contains the correct date from source database,

```
String sourceDate = "8/21/2012 2:09";
Timestamp sourceTS = Timestamp.valueOf(sourceDate);
System.out.println(sourceTS.getNanos());
```

Here is the post: [Convert Java String to sql.Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628103/convert-java-string-to-sql-timestamp).

Comment: Of course, even with this you can have problems - namely, timestamps in DB2 lack timezone specifiers.  So if your application server is set to something different than the DB2 instance, you might end up with modified times regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this TS to String, String to TS... but...

1. Post the pattern that you used in "format" object (SimpleDateFormat?).
2. What do "item.getMyTimeStamp()"? B) return a sql.Timestamp object?

If 2.B == true:

Maybe this be correct:

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(item.getMyTimeStamp().getTime()));
```

Comment: No. item.getMyTimeStamp() returns the String value I am talking about. The format is : java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: and you can't change anything of getMyTimeStamp? can post the code of "item" Object?
If you can change getMyTimeStamp() to return full-precision and change Pattern of DateFormat... problem solved.

Comment: getMyTimeStamp() does return full precision. Issue is pattern only. I can't find the correct pattern I require.

Comment: If you print the String value of getMyTimeStamp() you can find the pattern in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like... "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"