# MYSQL ADDTIME method gives exception : Java.lang.string cannot be cast to timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a query which fetches data and time from db, I am using addtime method of mysql to concat the two columns and return a single column.

IN mysql 5.5 the same query gave the result with return type as timestamp in java. I upgraded the db to 5.6 and now the result is in string and so the code gives exception that "String cannot be cast to Timestamp".
My Query is

```
SELECT offerId , 
       status,  
       ADDTIME(effective_date_end, effective_time_end) asn endDateTime from offer
```

Data type of effective_date_end is date and that of effective_time_end is time.

After getting the result i am doing this in my java code.

```
java.sql.Timestamp)offerDetailMap.get("endDateTime")
```

This line now gives error.

Is there any way to get the two fields merged and return a time stamp in mysql 5.6?

Comment: Could you post the Java code which getting this error?

Comment: Timestamp offerEndDate = (java.sql.Timestamp)offerDetailMap.get("endDateTime")

Answer (score 1):

As much as I would love to claim credit for an answer, I believe you might be looking for the answer given here:
[Convert Java String to sql.Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628103/convert-java-string-to-sql-timestamp)

Comment: Thats working. But i want to retive the column with data type as Timestamp instead of string. This was working in 5.5.