# converting string to timestamp hive

Tags: java, timestamp

my data file and hence my stage table in hive, has time in the following format 1/1/2013 5:27:35 PM. I want to load this data into another table that has time in the TIMESTAMP data type format. So basically the above format needs to be transformed to 2013-01-01 17:27:35. How to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Java String to sql.Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628103/convert-java-string-to-sql-timestamp)

Comment: You could do it using my answer too..

Answer (score 0):

you could try in java:

```
    String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        System.out.println("Input: " + dateStart);
        System.out.println("Output: " + sdf.format(d1));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Output**

```
Input: 01/14/2012 09:29:58
Output: 2012-01-14 09:29:58
```