# How do I validate a timestamp in scala?

Tags: scala

my application takes in a string like this "2002-10-15 10:55:01.000000". I need to validate inside scala script that the string is a valid for a db2 timestamp.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7628103/3801695).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general (I'd guess) you would do it moslty the same way as in *java* with either `java.text.DateFormat` or `joda.time.DateTimeFormat` (see [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)).

A simple example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

import scala.util.Try

val date = "2002-10-15 10:55:01.000000"
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSS")

val test = Try[Date](formatter.parse(date))
```

would give you:

```
test: scala.util.Try[java.util.Date] = Success(Tue Oct 15 10:55:01 CEST 2002)
```

Then you could match:

```
test match {
    case Success(date) => // ok
    case Failure(exception) => // not ok
}
```

Comment: hey, can we retrieve only status like "Success" or "Failure" out of above result, i tried test.take(7) to retrieve status only but its saying test.scala:13: error: value take is not a member of scala.util.Try[java.util.Dat
e]
         if (test.take(7)=="Success")
                 ^
one error found

Comment: Try works much like a usual `try-catch-block` wrapped in something like an `Option` or rather an `Either`. So, the result of `Try.apply[Date]` is either a `Success(date: Date)` or a `Failure(ex: _ <: Throwable)`.  You can check whether or not the `Try` was successful with either `test.isSuccess` or `test.isFailure`. However, with the `match` you can also look inside a `Success` to get the actual parsed `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` of java to do that in scala :

```
 object DateParser {
      def isValid(f : String, d : String) = {
        try {
          val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(f)
          format.parse(d)
        }catch(java.text.ParseException e) {
          false
        }
      }
      def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val format = "yyyy-MM-dd k:m:s"
        println(isValid(format,"2002-10-15 10:55:01.000000"))
        println(isValid(format,"2002-10-1510:55:01.000000"))
      }
    }
```